# "ERROR getting 'android:icon' attribute: attribute is not a string value" when trying to upload to the Android Market

Tags: android, icons, android-manifest, google-play

There's not a similar question here, but Googling around some other people have had the same issue. None of the recommended fixes are working.

The full error is:

> The file is invalid: W/ResourceType(32055): Failure getting entry for
>   0x7f050001 (t=4 e=1) in package 0 (error -75) ERROR getting
>   'android:icon' attribute is not a string value

Here's my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.dominoes"
      android:versionCode="10"
      android:versionName="2.00">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/myicon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Dominoes"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" 
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" 
            android:targetSdkVersion="4" />
            <supports-screens
          android:largeScreens="true"
          android:normalScreens="true"
          android:smallScreens="true"
          android:anyDensity="false" />  
</manifest>
```

The image, "myicon.png", is located in the res/drawable folder. It's a 96x96 .png.

Answer (score 16):

Well, after screwing with this stupid bug for a couple of hours, I found the answer on my own. This is one of my few apps that is localized into Spanish, so my res directory had the following:

res/values-en

res/values-es

This apparently worked fine in previous versions of the Android Market. I think the last time I updated this app was over a year ago.

Anyway, turns out I needed just a plain values directory:

res/values

res/values-en

res/values-es

I just copied the contents of the values-en directory into the values directory and now the Android Market is happy and let me upload my .apk. I hadn't seen this particular answer in any of the research I came across, so hopefully this helps someone.

Comment: You can accept your own answer and this will help others in future

Comment: another common issue on uploading is that you do have the values folder but some literals are missing in the default strings.xml file while these are present in the translations. Also I've seen 'android:icon' but also 'android:label' in the error message.

Answer (score 6):

You have to put the icon used in your main drawable folder. You don't have to delete the icons from the other folders, leave them with the different sizes of icons but put at least one of them in the drawable.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I put the icon.png to all the drawable- folders(xdpi mdpi and others). 
To solve it I removed all the icons from drawable- folders(xdpi mdpi and others) and put a 96x96 one to the drawable folder and problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

With the latest Play store reqs, you might need to put your android:icon drawable from your AndroidManifest.xml file into a "drawable" folder or "drawable-nodpi" folder if you only have it in bucket related folders like "drawable-large-land" or other folders that specify bucket related resources.

In my case, i just copied the resource I use for my app icon into my "drawable-nodpi" folder and the Play store accepted my apk.