# Error while uploading apk to android market

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest, google-play

I am trying to add my app to the android market. but i am facing the following error:

"**The file is invalid: W/ResourceType(17963): Failure getting entry for 0x7f050003 (t=4 e=3) in package 0 (error -75) ERROR getting 'android:icon' attribute: attribute is not a string value**"

My manifest file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.shaer.Hadith"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".HadithActivity" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">"
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".HadithsList">
        </activity>
     <activity
            android:name=".Hadith">
        </activity>   
    </application>
</manifest>
```

"ic_launcher" is included in the "res/drawable-hdpi", "res/drawable-ldpi" and "res/drawable-mdpi" directories.

I followed this post but it didn't work for me. 
["ERROR getting 'android:icon' attribute: attribute is not a string value" when trying to upload to the Android Market](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474526/error-getting-androidicon-attribute-attribute-is-not-a-string-value-when-t)

Thanks a lot in advance.

I created a "res/drawable" directory and added my icon "ic_launcher" in it but still no difference.

Comment: put "ic_launcher" is included in the "res/drawable"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally it has been solved.

The app was localized in two languages. So, I had three string file ("/res/values/strings.xml", "/res/values-en/strings.xml" and "/res/values-fr/stings.xml").

I defined variables in the two the english and french string files. The program worked fine as i tried it on english and french emulators.

but some strings weren't defined in the default strings.xml file!!!!

It is a silly mistake but the error from the android market is misleading =)

hope this answer will help some new developers (like me =) ) and save time some time

Comment: @SERPRO don't forget there's a time restriction stopping you marking your own answer as correct after it's been posted.