# Error while uploading application to android-market

Tags: android, google-play

I have signed the android application in eclipse by exporting it. But when i try to upload the .apk file to market i recieve the bellow error

Your APK cannot be analyzed using 'aapt dump badging'. Error output:
Failed to run aapt dump badging:
W/ResourceType(32345): No known package when getting value for resource number 0x01080057
ERROR getting 'android:icon' attribute: attribute is not a string value

Below is my Manifiest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="c.programs.simplified.vinay"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.motorola.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.motorola.dlauncher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.fede.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.lge.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="org.adw.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.motorola.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.motorola.dlauncher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.lge.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.apperhand.device.android.EULAActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        <activity
            android:name="c.programs.simplified.vinay.Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="standard"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Splash" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="c.programs.simplified.vinay.programview"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_view"
            android:launchMode="standard"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="c.programs.simplified.vinay.MainActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="standard"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3):

I got same problem because values folder doesn't contain string.xml. 
I built it on values-th and values-en. then i move string.xml from values-en to values. that's was fixed!!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be related to default values folder or string file or icon required in drawable folder.
Please have a look at these answers which have already helped few.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10452390/989418

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7475737/989418

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11852699/989418

[Error while uploading apk to android market](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819400/error-while-uploading-apk-to-android-market)

http://www.blackmoonit.com/2010/07/market-disallow-use-of-android-icons/

http://blog.accidentallyproductive.com/2012/10/so-this-is-problem-that-we-ran-into.html

Comment: I resolved the problem. Thanx Sourab Sharma. I have changed 
android:icon = "@drawable/icon"

Comment: If your solution is different from above links solutions, please add as an answer to your own question so that it can help others too in future.

Comment: I resolved the problem. I have changed android:icon = "@drawable/icon". The Default was 
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_view" in one of the activity. Change that to I have changed android:icon = "@drawable/icon" and problem got resolved. Hope it help others too :)