# “ERROR getting 'android:icon' attribute: attribute is not a string value”

Tags: android, apk, google-play

I get this error while I was uploading .apk to Google Play:

```
Upload failed
Your APK cannot be analysed using 'aapt dump badging'. Error output: <pre>Failed to  run aapt dump badging: W/ResourceType(19605): Failure getting entry for 0x7f070000 (t=6 e=0) in package 0 (error -75) ERROR getting &#39;android:icon&#39; attribute: attribute is not a string value</pre>
```

I have icon image under drawable folder with 96x96 size.

I had values-sr folder for some translation, but I deleted that folder because I don't need that translation now.

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

<supports-screens                                 
android:smallScreens="true"                    
android:normalScreens="true"         
android:largeScreens="true"            
android:xlargeScreens="true"             
android:anyDensity="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.zookey.mathgenius.HomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"
         >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.zookey.mathgenius.activities.LocalGameActivity" android:noHistory="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.zookey.mathgenius.activities.ResultActivity" android:noHistory="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.zookey.mathgenius.activities.TimedResultActivity" android:noHistory="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.zookey.mathgenius.activities.RaceResultActivity" android:noHistory="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.zookey.mathgenius.activities.RaceRankActivity" android:noHistory="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.zookey.mathgenius.activities.OnlineRaceRankActivity" android:noHistory="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.zookey.mathgenius.activities.OnlineRaceResultActivity" android:noHistory="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.zookey.mathgenius.activities.SettingsActivity" android:noHistory="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.zookey.mathgenius.activities.HelpActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
</application>
```

Comment: In the `string.xml` file, is there a string by the name of `app_name'. Do check other attributes as well. Some times it shows the error about icon but there is an issue with other paramerters like `android:label` etc. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452008/android-market-publishing-androidicon-attribute-attribute-is-not-a-string-v

Comment: I have string app_name in string.xml. Is that ok?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar problem when uploaded an app. Turns out that the app icon in my manifest:
 android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" had corresponding files under /res/drawable-small, /res/drawable-normal, /res/drawable-large and /res/drawable-xlarge but *not* under /res/drawable. Looks like the automated process of Google Play only looks up /res/drawable. Copying the app icon into this directory did the trick for me.