# android failure getting some entry

Tags: android

I have a simple `Activity` displaying a custom `Dialog` with some `RadioGroups`, nothing special. While working with the app, I noticed some strange LogCat output marked as warning and tagged ResourceType:

```
07-19 23:29:18.073: W/ResourceType(32621): Failure getting entry for 0x010802c1 (t=7 e=705) in package 0 (error -75)
```

My app is working as intended (though I have less then 10% finished at this point), I couldn't notice any issues. Anyone knows the meaning of this warning and if there could be any related problems in the future?

P.S. the warning is shown while testing on a rooted SGS2 I9100 (4.1.2 JB) and does not appear while testing on SGS Note N7000 (also 4.1.2)

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474526/error-getting-androidicon-attribute-attribute-is-not-a-string-value-when-t . Its related so might be helpful Are you having `res/values` folder?

Comment: sure I have. My app is intended to be English-only, so I have only one

Comment: So, you've checked what `0x010802c1` corresponds to in `R.java`? And that its where its supposed to be?

Comment: the matter is that there's no corresponding entry in R.java... And this message does not always appear. Well I guess this might be some ADT bug

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is a resource problem. I am having the same Warning message because Android SDK (eclipse) stopped support to generate **icons** for **res/drawable-ldpi**. And the testing device is one with a smaller screen which requires low DPI icons. [According to Google](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Screens), 9.9% of the devices are ldpi and this number is decreasing over time.

Because you mentioned Samsung I9100, it is a ldpi device and it is normal to have this warning.

This message shows that the resource is not found and other icons are used after resizing. It can be ignored if you don't want to create such icons manually.