# W/ResourceType(463): Failure getting entry in package 0 (error -75) in Android Activity

Tags: android, android-resources

In one `Activity` (it's a `SherlockActivity`, by the way) of my Android application, I have a normal `ListView`.

For that `ListView`, I set an `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` via `getListView().setOnItemClickListener(...)`.

And in that listener, an `AlertDialog` is built using the `AlertDialog.Builder` class and then it is shown to the user:

```
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View v, int position, long id) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
        ...
        builder.setMessage(Html.fromHtml(...));
        builder.show();
    }
}
```

Now exactly when `builder.show()` is called, the following warning does *always* appear in LogCat:

```
W/ResourceType(463): Failure getting entry for 0x010802c9 (t=7 e=713) in package 0 (error -75)
```

Where does this come from? To me, it seems this is out of my control, as it appears with `builder.show()`, so that this warning is maybe generated somewhere in the sources for the `AlertDialog` class. Is this true?

If not, how can I find which resource is missing? How to debug this warning?

**Edit:** There's no corresponding entry for `0x010802c9` (or whichever value that is at run time) in `R.java`, so I really don't know how to debug this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [android failure getting some entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755967/android-failure-getting-some-entry)

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: There's only one answer there, which is definitely not the solution to my problem. And there's another "related question" linked, but neither that question's solution is helpful.

Comment: It was a solution to me for exactly the same line in logcat.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to open it from worker thread instead of GUI thread?
You can check if the thread is GUI thread with:

`Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()`

In order to be sure that it is opened from GUI thread, use handler or [runOnUiThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method.

Comment: This does not change anything. The expression that you proposed does already evaluate to `true`, and `runOnUiThread(...)` does not have any effect, therefore. By the way, if calling from the wrong thread been the cause for the problem, you would have seen `java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()` before ;) Thanks, anyway!