# Which Resource is referred to by an ID

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have an Android App written using Xamarin for Visual Studio.  When it runs I get the warning:

Failure getting entry for 0x01080acd (t=7 e=2765) (error -75)

I know there is something wrong with one of my resources, but I can't seem to figure out which resource has the ID of 0x01080acd.  I tried looking at it while debugging in the activity OnCreate method, but it doesn't seem to work.  Any suggestions on how I might track this down?

Jim

Answer (score 1):

If that is truly a resource ID, open the file *Resource.Designer.cs* in the *Resources* folder of your project.

Search for **17304269** (decimal for 0x01080acd).

If there's a match, that'll be the ID.

Otherwise, it might be a global resource or some other value.

Comment: I looked for that.  All of the values in the Resource.Designer.cs begin with a 2.  I have stepped through the program and found that the error occurs when I inflate a particular screen, but it is a very complicated layout and has three embedded layouts in it.

Comment: Try doing a clean build. Sometimes resources get in an invalid state and can cause issues. I always do this anytime I update Xamarin or any of the Android SDK tools.

Comment: Yeah that was the first thing I did back when I first got the warning.  One thing is that I had to revert my version of Xamarin, because a feature I was using related to the task factory was causing an error.  It has been fixed in Mono, but won't be released in Xamarin until October.  Maybe that will fix this warning as well.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a problem with a resource then check the naming, resources must not start with number and use only letters and _ and also not any capital latter.

Check also here for naming rules http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#QualifierRules maybe you have made an icon for some resolutions and forget to make it for others,

like in this similar question [android failure getting some entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755967/android-failure-getting-some-entry)