# Android - Failure getting entry for 0x010802c8 (t=7 e=712) in package 0 (error -75)

Tags: android, xml, runtime-error, android-logcat, calendarview

I have an android app that runs fine in my genymotion emulator, which has a virtual device of api 23, the problem is when I run it in a device with an api of 16, I realized the problem of this error that the Logcat is throwing is because I have a calendarView in my XML layout.

How can I fix this? I need the calendarView to work fine in this api level.

**Error:**

```
Failure getting entry for 0x010802c8 (t=7 e=712) in package 0 (error -75)
```

Comment: Check this answer:http://stackoverflow.com/a/20300077/5089018

Comment: @DsD thats not the same error

Comment: did u find the solution

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when any resource that you are using for in your xml is not compatible. Try to comment each resource one by one and check which resource is causing the problem. Replace the resource with the type of resource which doesnt causes the error.

In my case a v24 xml file was used as the resource for an image and was causing the issue. Then i replaced that xml with a png file in the xml of the activity. Now the issue is resolved.