# My app crashes on API 16 - 24 but works on API 25 up when I use ImageViews

Tags: java, android, android-layout

My app crashes with the error ***"Unfortunately app has stopped"*** every time on android emulators with `API 16 to 24` but runs on `API 24` up when using ImageView. However, it works correctly when Imageview is removed. I need the ImageView for the project am building. How can I solve this? Below is my xml code:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/note1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:text="@string/note1"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/note2"/>

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_end="20dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/note2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/note2"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/note1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/barrier"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"

    />

<android.support.constraint.Barrier
    android:id="@+id/barrier"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:barrierDirection="bottom"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="note1,note2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/logoimage"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttongradient"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:text="@string/button_name"
android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Menu"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/barrier2" />

<android.support.constraint.Barrier
    android:id="@+id/barrier2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:barrierDirection="top"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
     />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logoimage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/barrier2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/barrier"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.godwinacquah.ourstudybuddy;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Intent load;
Button but1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    but1 = findViewById(R.id.button);

    but1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            load = new Intent( MainActivity.this ,Home.class);
            startActivity(load);
            finish();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {


    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
  }

 }
```

**logcat**

```
08-08 15:46:40.522 3506-3506/com.example.godwinacquah.ourstudybuddy W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f070097 (t=6 e=151) in package 0 (error -75)
Failure getting entry for 0x7f070097 (t=6 e=151) in package 0 (error -75)
08-08 15:46:40.522 3506-3506/com.example.godwinacquah.ourstudybuddy D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
08-08 15:46:40.522 3506-3506/com.example.godwinacquah.ourstudybuddy W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x9cd74b20)
08-08 15:46:40.532 3506-3506/com.example.godwinacquah.ourstudybuddy E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.godwinacquah.ourstudybuddy, PID: 3506
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.godwinacquah.ourstudybuddy/com.example.godwinacquah.ourstudybuddy.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #100: Error inflating class ImageView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #100: Error inflating class ImageView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:714)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
    at com.example.godwinacquah.ourstudybuddy.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070097
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1123)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getValue(ResourcesWrapper.java:208)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:328)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:193)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:186)
    at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:58)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:77)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:67)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:181)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:105)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1035)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1092)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
    at com.example.godwinacquah.ourstudybuddy.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
08-08 15:46:40.562 3506-3506/com.example.godwinacquah.ourstudybuddy D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 328K, 11% free 3297K/3700K, paused 17ms, total 26ms
08-08 15:46:40.632 1629-3519/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2846K, 40% free 12585K/20720K, paused 70ms, total 71ms
```

Comment: where are you calling the ImageView's id?

Comment: @Addo, drawable logo is vector image ??

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755967/android-failure-getting-some-entry

Comment: Be sure `logo` is placed inside `drawable` folder.

Comment: the logo is placed inside drawable folder, its not a vector image. i imported it into the project

Answer (score 0):

"@drawable/logo" is a vector image? If yes, you need to add the support libary in to graddle dependencies

Graddle:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.app"
    minSdkVersion 15
    versionCode 1
    versionName "x"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}

dependencies {
//...
compile "com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:$appcompatVersion"
}
```

Comment: the dependencies gave this error "Could not get unknown property 'appcompatVersion' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler."

Comment: My bad. Replace the "$appcompatVersion" string with your current appCompatVersion. Just look the others com.android.support dependencies.
Eg:
compile "com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1"